# NGINX Internal directive inside a location block

Tags: nginx

In this case what is `internal` doing inside the `location` block?

```
error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
location = /custom_404.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}
```

Comment: See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal

Answer (score 1):

NGINX differentiates external and internal requests. External requests originate directly from the client; the URI is then matched against possible location blocks and appropriate actions are executed.

Opposite to this, internal requests are triggered by NGINX via specific directives. Among the directives offered by the default NGINX modules, there are several directives capable of producing internal requests: `error_page`, `index`, `rewrite`, `try_files` etc.